# Downloading bucket contents

Tags: download, gsutil

I issued the following command to download all of the content of a bucket.

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://"lynda_gcs_bucket_lsb" /gcs2/ .
```

Below is a screenshot of GSUTIL copying bucket contents. GSUTIL tells me that the contents were downloaded but I can't find the files anywhere. Where are they? I have tried issuing a path to direct where the downloaded files should be placed.

[image]

Comment: I removed the " around the bucket name. Still looks like it is copying but is not.

Comment: Where would you like the contents to go?  The command as you've typed it (without the quotes) will copy the contents of lynda_gcs_bucket_lsb and whatever is at /gcs2/ to the current working directory, which you can see by running 'pwd'.